# find: cannot fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: shell, find, memory, deleted-files

I want to delete 1 file at a time from my directory which contains so many files, so I want to remove 1 file at a time. Just to avoid too many reads and failed at too many arguments.

```
    find ./Backup/ -name '*.csv' -maxdepth 1 -exec rm {} \;
    find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -name, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

    find: cannot fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

I don't want to delete recursively from a child directory thats why -maxdepth 1.
Any help and suggestion?

Comment: It's weird that you're getting that fork error but `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} \;` should solve it. Other than that, just move `-maxdepht 1` before `-name`. Don't forget to test without `-delete` first.

Comment: The `-exec ... '{}' \+` form of `find` might save on forks, as this emulates `xargs` in (modern) versions of `find`.

Comment: @thrig It saves *successive* forks, which doesn't really help with a process limit.

Comment: Do you have stringent limits on your account? What operating system and distribution is the system running? Are you running a lot of other processes?

Comment: Yes,Its a production env. There are so many procsses running on a system.

Comment: Its Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The `cannot fork` message might appear when the swap area is full. The `tmpfs` filesystem (probably) mounted on `/tmp` might not have the necessary space for the kernel to create new processes.

Check if `/tmp` has still room using `df -h /tmp`. If it is full, try to cleanup `/tmp` first.

Comment: Swap and tmpfs are not related except in that they are both subsets of available memory. Room in `/tmp` is not necessary to create new processes. Room in memory is, but the amount is so small that removing things in `/tmp` is very unlikely to make a fork possible.

Comment: /tmp is not even close to full.

Comment: @Gilles, On Solaris `/tmp` is actual `tmpfs` and when it is completely (+100%) utilized you will get `unable to fork; not enough space` messages. The messages the OP get are `cannot fork; unable to allocate memory`. Apologies that I suggested a Solaris solution and did not ask for the OS first. The OP might check the values of `ulimit -a` and `ulimit -aH` to see if there is a memory limit which can be hit during this process. It is also worth trying to look at `/etc/security/limits.conf` to see if some limits are set.

Comment: I have had the same problem with lots of space in /tmp available, but no swap activated.  [code]swapon /dev/sdXn[/code] solved the issue.